# Conflicting types using jest next to karma, jasmine on Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, karma-jasmine

**Background**

I am working on a project that originated as a angular.js project. We are currently migrating everything to Angular. This means we have legacy unit tests for Angular.js which will eventually be removed. For Angular, we have migrated all tests to Jest.

**Problem**

The problem arises when trying to have both `Karma and Jasmine` as `Jest` in the project. The legacy unit tests are wired up with its own tsconfig file and these work fine. Both libraries seem to be adding the same functions to the global environment, and the Jest tests somehow keep resolving to the `Jasmine` types. If I remove `Karma and Jasmine` from the project all the tests work just fine.

**Question**

How can I can exclude `jasmine's` types like `expect` when running jest without removing `karma and jasmine` from the project altogether?

**I've tried**

I have a seperate `tsconfig.spec` file for the jest tests which I have referenced in the `jest.config.js` file. In this I've tried adding the wanted types only. Which I thought would only load `node_modules/@types/<included>`. But it will still include jasmine.

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node", "jquery", "jest"],
```

I've also tried including them through `typeRoots`, but this only gives me more errors like: `error TS2708: Cannot use namespace 'jest' as a value.`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types/jest"
      ...
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./*"]
    },
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "files": ["polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["./app/**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Somehow I do not seem able to make TypeScript ignore the `node_modules/@types/jasmine`. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried traceResolution compiler option to maybe see when/from where jasmine type file is loaded/referenced?

Comment: I'm also having a similar issue as I have a monorepo which is merging my jest and jasmine @types into one node_modules folder. Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: No, we are using the jasmine types for now until we can remove it completely. There where a couple of Typescript errors which I had to fix by prefixing `jasmine.`. Been a while, but I think for things like jasmine.any(Function) and so.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jest-without-globals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-without-globals) to explicitly import describe, expect, it, and test, overriding the global versions of these symbols which would otherwise be resolved from Jasmine.